# What is the difference between psutil and sar for Linux cpu usage?

Tags: linux, psutil, sar

What is the difference between psutil and sar for Linux cpu usage?
For example, I want to know which resource and computation.

Answer (score 0):

**psutil (process and system utilities)**-is a cross-platform library for retrieving information on running processes and system utilization (CPU, memory, disks, network, sensors) in Python. It is useful mainly for system monitoring, profiling and limiting process resources and management of running processes.

**SAR(System Activity Report)**-is used to collect,report & save CPU, Memory, I/O usage in Unix like operating system. SAR command produce the reports on the fly and can also save the reports in the log files as well.